# In Jenkins, what does the "Publish to Subversion repository" in Add post-build action dropdown do?

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, git-svn, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins.

I have a project in GIT. and I have configured it in Jenkins. The same project also exists in a svn repo.

I want to know...
In Jenkins, what does the "**Publish to Subversion repository**" in Add post-build action drop-down do ?

Will it check-in the code to SVN when it detects a check-in GIT ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer...

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher

It says that the Publish to svn repository plugin allows you to upload artifacts to a subversion repository.

Comment: Do you know more about it ? ie how will it upload to repository ? Can I make diffrent directory in repository to upload this new build ?

Comment: You can use Jenkins Artifactory Plugin (for deploying the built Maven artifacts to the Snapshot repository).If the artifact is to be imported into a directory other then the one given by the SVN URL "path"field can be used.